# How to wrap long text in html emails

Tags: html, email, ckeditor, html-email

Hoping someone can help. I have some HTML email templates in my app, they work fine and look great in litmus. A lot of the content in the email is user generated via a UI/editor (CKeditor in this case). For the most part, this works fine unless a user adds a very long string or link which then causes either the long link/text to break out of the container or breaks the layout completely depending on the email client.

The editor wraps text in `<p>` tags which I can't easily access to add a fix. The parent `<td>` has styles that I'd hope prevent the issue (and do if the content wasn't wrapped in a `<p>`). The TD looks like this:

```
<td class="content-block" style="margin: 0; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding: 0 0 20px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;">{{- editorText -}}</td>
```

I have a `<style>` block at the top of the email template that tries to fix the issue:

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
            ... some other styles ...

            .content-block p {
                display: inline-block !important;
                width: 560px !important;
                overflow-wrap: break-word !important; 
                word-wrap: break-word !important; 
                word-break: break-all !important; 
                word-break: break-word !important;
            }}
</style>
```

However this makes no difference and things still break with a long string of text.

Feels like I'm missing something obvious here... is there no way to fix other than adding inline styles to the `<p>` tag, which is going to be difficult to do.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about an unbroken string? like a very long URL? ex: `http://www.yoursite.com/?something&?somevariable&?otherthing=stuffwithnobreaksinthetext` ?

Comment: what about adding a `<span>` with the styles before your variable?

Comment: **What email clients are you seeing breakage on?** `word-break: break-all;` should do the trick. I can appreciate that you can't edit the `<p>` tag, though not all email clients support the `<style>` tag and they might not be getting that part of your CSS.

Comment: Can you post an example with the text issues? Lorem Ipsum is fine. What I'd like to know if it's the length of the entire text (2-3 pages), the length of a url as @scoopzilla mentioned or is it specific with one email reader (gmail, IOS, etc).

Comment: To answer the above, the issue is caused by a long unbroken string, so a long link for example. Adding `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;` to the parent `<td>` fixes the issue in all emails clients apart from the different outlook versions (2013, 2016 and outlook.com). I'm 99% sure if I could access the `<p>` tag the editor adds and add `word-break: break-all` it would fix it, but I can't.

@scoopzilla I've tried that, however, wrapping a `<p>` with a `<span>` isn't valid mark up and doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. 
I tried this and it worked for me.

```
<td style = "word-break: normal; border-collapse : collapse !important;"> 
Lorem Ipsium 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that not every Emailclient supports every html/css tags. Here you can see a [List of supported HTML/CSS Tags](https://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support) (If the link isn't available: search for email template supported tags)

I would suggest to code the wrapping yourself, for example with inserting a `<br>` Tag after a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe get the maximum width of the email and set it as such:

```html
<td style="max-width: 502px; overflow: hidden;">
```

There's no one solution that's guaranteed to work on all email clients.